# Databricks withcoloumn columns based on a condition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am new to the world of Spark and I am currently working on creating a dynamic column based on the example provided below. I have a dictionary of rules and I am creating a column by evaluating the values.

```
rules = {}
rules["valid_website"] = "(Website IS NOT NULL)"
rules["valid_location"] = "(Location IS NOT NULL)"
quarantine_rules = "NOT({0})".format(" AND ".join(rules.values()))
df2=df2.withColumn("is_valid", expr(quarantine_rules))
```

The above code successfully inserts the "is_valid" column. However, I would like to also insert a "Rules_applied" column that captures the rule name (key) when the corresponding value is generated. Ideally,for the is_valid columsn which is set, do i need to re-iterate?. Dont have a clue. please help.

**EDIT**

Tried the code below and now getting an error ***TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Column found***

```
rules = {}
rules["valid_website"] = "(Website IS NOT NULL)"
rules["valid_location"] = "(Location IS NOT NULL)"
quarantine_rules = "{0}".format(" AND ".join(validity_rules.values()))

@dlt.table(name="validity_application")
@dlt.expect_all(validity_rules)
def get_quarantined_application():
    return (
        dlt.read("msf_raw_application")
        .withColumn("is_valid", expr(quarantine_rules))
        .withColumn("Rules_applied",
         expr("concat_ws(',', {})".format(", ".join([when(col(rule_expr), lit(rule_name)) for rule_name, rule_expr in rules.items()]))))
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the solution

```
def get_quarantined_application():
    return (
        dlt.read("msf_raw_application")
        .withColumn("is_valid", expr(quarantine_rules))
        .withColumn("Rules_applied", when(expr(quarantine_rules)=='false',array([when(expr(rule_expr), lit(rule_name)) for rule_name, rule_expr in validity_rules.items()])))
    )
```

Comment: Here the rule is being evaluated twice, that may be inefficient if too many records are evaluated. You can simply write a function, pass column and rule def and return a tuple of which rules are evaluated and final result.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Column found
> This means the function `format` is expecting a String but `when(col(rule_expr), lit(rule_name)` is returning a Column because `lit` function converts `rule_name` to a column.

How about,
 `expr("concat_ws(',', {})".format(", ".join([when(col(rule_expr), rule_name) for rule_name, rule_expr in rules.items()]))))`